# Nginx SSL fail Expecting any private key

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm having trouble configuring my SSL to use with nginx. I'm not sure how to solve the problem, is there anyone someone might know the solution or can put me on the right track?

**Error**

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/ssl/test.key") failed (SSL: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib)
```

**nginx config**

```
listen   443 ssl;
ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/test.crt;
ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/test.key;
```

**ausearch -m avc -ts today | audit2allow**

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t user_home_t:file read;
```

Comment: Your `test.key` does not contain the key or does not have the proper format. Possible duplicate of [nginx config fails with SSL key/pem (unique case)](https://serverfault.com/questions/571377/nginx-config-fails-with-ssl-key-pem-unique-case)

Comment: How did you create this private key?

Comment: It was generated for me from go daddy @MichaelHampton

Comment: That's unusual, and certainly not recommended. Have you looked at it?

Comment: So, what would be recommended? Should I have my own DNS server going and avoid go daddy?

Comment: DNS service and SSL certificate are separate things and need not be done by the same provider. And normally **you** would create the private key, use it to sign a certificate signing request, which the SSL provider will turn into a certificate. The SSL provider should not create and indeed never see your private key.

Comment: (But generally speaking, I personally recommend pretty much any other DNS provider - GoDaddy have had quite a few security, privacy, and technical issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring it with LetsEncrypt SSL with certbot. For more information see here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

If u want self-signed cert. then click here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04